# how can I access the value of key from header in log stash coming from kafka producer header

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash

I am ingesting data from Kafka to Elasticsearch through Log stash, everything ok. but I have different topic and in one topic many events types. I get topic name but when I want to get event type from Kafka producer I am unable to get them. what should I do ?
I want to get event type from header of Kafka producer. header is separately sent in Kafka producer method.
my Kafka producer code is where header is send

```
public async Task<bool> KafkaProducerEvent([FromBody] PModel model, string topic, string Keyvalue, string eventType)
            {
                try
                {
                    var conf = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = _configuration["producer:bootstrap_servers"] };
                    conf.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl;
                    conf.SaslUsername = _configuration["producer:sasl_username"];
                    conf.SaslPassword = _configuration["producer:sasl_password"];
                    conf.SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain;
    
                    string SerializedModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                    string eventType = "Service_ContentPage_Added";
                    var Headersvalue = new Headers()
                    {
                        { "eventKey", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString())},
                         { "eventType" ,Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(eventType.ToString())}
                    };
    
                    using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string?, string?>(conf).Build())
                    {
    
                        producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<string?, string?> { Key = Keyvalue, Value = SerializedModel, Headers = Headersvalue });
                        producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }   
    
    
    
    -----------------------------------
     var pmodel = new PModel
                    {
                        Description = model.Description1,
                        ServiceId = model.ServiceId
                    };
                    var topic = _configuration["producer:ServiceCreate-topic"];
                    string keyValue = model.ServiceId.ToString();
                    string eventType = "Service_ContentPage_Added";
                    var kafkaresult = _kafkaservices.KafkaProducerEvent(pmodel, topic, keyValue, eventType);
    
    
    ------------------------------------
  

      public Task<bool> KafkaProducerEvent([FromBody] PModel model, string topic, string Keyvalue, string eventType);
```

my log stash config file

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => '
      headers = event.get("[headers]")
      if headers.is_a?(String)
        begin
          parsed_headers = JSON.parse(headers)
          event.set("event_type", parsed_headers["eventType"])
        rescue => e
          # Handle JSON parsing error if necessary
          event.set("event_type", nil)
        end
      end
    '
  }
}
```

```
I also used this one
```

```
 filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "event_type" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][headers][eventType]}"
    }
  }
}
```

with each approach not satisfied I cant get the event type from header , my header response look like

```
[
  {
    "key": "eventKey",
    "value": "12/04/2023 13:30:18"
  },
  {
    "key": "eventType",
    "value": "Service_ContentPage_Added"
  }
]
```

Thanks